# How can we get the specific part of text from element in cypress

Tags: cypress

`<span _ngcontent-khc-c105="" class="m-r-32">Page 1 of 1</span>`

I want to get text from this element but not complete, i want to extract on last '1' from it
I am using following method

```
    paginationPageCount=Cypress.$(text).text()
    cy.log(paginationPageCount)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the text will always be something like `Page X of Y`, then we can use a little JS the callback from the `cy.get()` (or similar function to find the element).

```js
cy.get('span') // update to find your specific element
  .then(($el) => {
    cy.log($el.text().split('of ')[1]);
  });
```

If you need to store the value somewhere, you can either create a variable outside of the Cypress chain and assign it the value during Cypress' execution, or store it in a Cypress environment variable.

```js
let pageMax;
cy.get('span') // update to find your specific element
  .then(($el) => {
    pageMax = $el.text().split('of ')[1]; // assign value to variable
    Cypress.env('pageMax', pageMax); // assign value to Cypress environment variable named 'pageMax')
  }).then(() => {
    cy.log(pageMax)
      .log(Cypress.env(pageMax));
  });
```

Comment: In the 2nd code block, your logs aren't going to work. They need to be inside a `.then()`.

Comment: Why do they need to be inside of a `.then()`? The Cypress chain won't continue until after the values are set in the first `.then()`, so the `.log()` commands shouldn't occur until the variables have values.

Comment: Test it, you will see it's true. Because the `.log()` commands are enqueued with the initial value `undefined` before the queue starts running. Any code inside a `.then()` isn't run until that point in the queue, so now `.log()` commands are enqueued with updated values.

Comment: What is lacking in Cypress commands is deferred or lazy evaluation, which is what everyone assumes will happen. For example the syntax `.log(() => pageMax)` could be used to wait until the queue runs the log command to obtain it's value.

Comment: Ah you're right. Got myself mixed up with how Cypress blocks other functions from running.